# Upgrading tabulator from 4.2 to 5.2 - Table not initialized

Tags: tabulator

I am upgrading from Tabulator 4.2.7 to 5.2 and am getting table not initialized. I have simply replaced the CDN reference with the new one . Is there something else I should be doing?

```
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<!--
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
-->
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct behaviour from 5.0 and is why you see the message in the console.

Using the data property on the table constructor is the correct way to initialize the table data.

This happens because Tabulator now initializes asynchronously, this happens for two reasons, the first is to allow consistent initialization between async and synchronous data sources, the second is to allow binding of events to the table before initialization is completed, to catch things like the tableBuilt event.

If you want to continue to use the setData to initialize the data in your table (which is unnecessary if you correctly initialize the data in the table using the data setup option) then you need to call it in the tableBuilt event which is fired after the table has been fully initialized

```
table.on("tableBuilt", function(){
    table.setData(data);
});
```

https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3407